# Can preview a XLSX or XLS in browser?

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, actionresult

I have a MVC ActionResult controller that download the file.

If the file is PDF then using this JS code

```
var $obj = $('<object>');
$obj.attr("type", "application/pdf");
$obj.attr("data", myurl);                            
$("#id").append($obj);
```

Then I can preview the PDF in my app.

I want something similar for XLSX or XLS files.

If I hit the URL I get the file but I cannot display it.

I tried with

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=myurl"></iframe>
```

but doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can preview the PDF because you have the according browser plugin installed. If you want the same for an Excel spreadsheet, you need a browser plugin to handle this.

Comment: so, without make anyone to install a plugin, i cannot display excel?

Comment: First see if you can directly open an XLS or XLSX file in your browser.  If the browser doesn't know what to do with that file then it won't be able to display it anyway.  (And even if your browser does, that doesn't mean other users will.)

Comment: If i hit my url, then the file is downloading, so i guess my server side knows

Comment: There is a javascript plugin to do this. https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: @GomuGomuNoRocket That's right. Without a browser plugin, users will be prompted to save the file download.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's been four years since the original post and the author likely no longer requires a solution, I recently encountered a similar need. I generate XLS reports and found myself repeatedly downloading and opening each file manually. While I was unable to find a method to preview these files directly in the browser, I developed a small script that monitors my Downloads directory for new XLS files. Whenever a new file is detected, the script automatically closes LibreOffice Calc (if it's open) and reopens it with the newly downloaded file.

Admittedly, this approach is not very elegant, but it gets the job done.

https://gist.github.com/tiriana/6f9b8fa7861592e3ac0c2271de502f46#file-watch_and_open-sh

Answer (score 0):

If you have a URL.xlsx as suggested by this question both Google and Microsoft provide Online Viewers.

Microsoft, clearly going to work best as compatible with most of their proprietary coded XLSX components.

https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https://www.sqa.org.uk/sqa/files_ccc/progression-2023-tables.xlsx
[image]

Google is a more basic viewer

[image]